# Eliminate first and last white spaces or tabs in LINUX

Tags: linux

I have a json file which elements are listed like this:

```
"URL": [      "R-MMU-72200"    ],

"GENES": [      "4706167874","4706170968"    ],

"NAME": [      "mRNA Editing: C to U Conversion"    ],

"ORGANISM": [      "Mus musculus"    ],

"PATH_MAP": [      "R-MMU-72200"    ]  },
```

I want to eliminate the white spaces or tabs that are at the beginning and the end of each of the strings within brackets. I would want this:

```
 "URL": ["R-MMU-72200"],

 "GENES": ["4706167874","4706170968"],

 "NAME": ["mRNA Editing: C to U Conversion"],

 "ORGANISM": ["Mus musculus"],

 "PATH_MAP": ["R-MMU-72200"]  },
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you really not try writing any code yet, or find any of the many other topics where such stripping of whitespace is discussed? SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: At least post valid JSON as an example. That is not valid JSON. Test [here](https://jsonlint.com)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
sed 's/\s\s//g'
```

Results in:

```
"URL": ["R-MMU-72200"],
```

Answer (score 1):

First, assuming you mean:

```
$ cat file
{"URL": [      "R-MMU-72200"    ],
"GENES": [      "4706167874","4706170968"    ],
"NAME": [      "mRNA Editing: C to U Conversion"    ],
"ORGANISM": [      "Mus musculus"    ],
"PATH_MAP": [      "R-MMU-72200"    ]  }
```

You can just run that through a JSON parser to remove the spaces.

Here is an example with `ruby`:

```
$ ruby -r json -e 'p JSON.parse($<.read)' file
{"URL"=>["R-MMU-72200"], "GENES"=>["4706167874", "4706170968"], "NAME"=>["mRNA Editing: C to U Conversion"], "ORGANISM"=>["Mus musculus"], "PATH_MAP"=>["R-MMU-72200"]}
```

Or, you can use `jq`:

```
$ jq '.' file
```